# Help with a special picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, rotating

inspired by the following graphic, I tried to copy it with tikz. I'd like to modify it in some details:
[image]

1. The rim of the coloured background should be homogeneous.
2. I don't want the bonds between the amino acids, I prefer them to be seperated

Here is my first try:

```
\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\usepackage{chemfig,xstring}
\begin{document}
\setatomsep{2.5em}
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 point/.style={circle,draw=none,minimum size=#1},
 point/.default=0pt % default Wert für minimum size bei point]
 \foreach \anfang/\ende/\farbe in { 25/100/green!60,104/170/orange!60,174 /254/red!60, 258/314/yellow!60, 318/381/blue!60}
\draw[fill=\farbe,draw=none] (0,0) -- (\anfang:12cm) arc (\anfang:\ende:12cm);
\draw[fill=white,draw=none] (0,0) circle (6cm);

% mit count=\i werden die Kreise nummeriert
% der zugehörige Winkel wird mit evaluate aus dieser Nummer berechnet
% insgesamt werden (bis zu) 20 Kreise auf 360 Grad gleichmäßig verteilt
\foreach[count=\i,evaluate=\i as \angle using (\i-1)*360/20] \text in {%
  1,2,3,4,\begin{tiny}\schemestart \chemnameinit{}\chemname{\chemfig{C(=[3]O)(-[1]OH)(-[6]CH_2(-[6]CH(-[5]NH_2)(-[7]C(=[6]O)(-[1]OH))))}}{Asparaginsäure\\Asp\\D} \schemestop\end{tiny},\begin{tiny}\schemestart \chemnameinit{} \chemname{\chemfig{CH(-[3]NH_2)(-[1]C(=[2]OH)(-[7]OH))(-[6]CH_2(-[6]C(=[5]O)(-[7]NH_2)))}}{Asparagin\\Asn\\N}\schemestop\end{tiny},7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20% Beschriftung der Kreise
}
\node[point=2.2em] (node\i) at (\angle:9) {\text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wrote the structure of the amino acids in an other TeX file and usually use the `\input` command. For the MWE two amino acids should be enough.

How can I rotate the nodes/amino acids so that they point to the center of the inner circle?

Any alternative solution is welcome, too.

I'm very sorry but I can't comment my own Question so I add the Information here.

@Alenanno thank you very much for your very helpful answer.

I don't want the same graphic. I actually like what I've got so far: all sturctural formulas in the coloured circle with nearly the same distance to the center.

Next step will be the outer description (small, polar (hydrophil) etc.). If it is possible respectively if I can manage it, I want the description to be below the structural formula at the inner rim of the coloured circle.

Can you tell me how to adress the single nodes?

What have you defined the \aminoacid command for? - I couldn't get it from the MWE

greets

@Alenanno:
That is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot! Is there a function to mark your answer beside the accepted button?

UPDATE:
This is my final output which fits perfect for me. Special thanks to Alenanno.
[image]

Comment: Apologies if English is not your first language, but in point 2. I think you mean "bond" (Bindung) rather than "bound" (Grenze).

Comment: Just a clarification: do you want the same scheme? As in: rectangles that appear at different distances from the center of the circle and colored the same way? Thanks. :)

Comment: @Alenanno You have mail ^^ ;). (I'm also not sure why you've defined that command. Is it just to put space around the argument so you get `<space><thing><space>` rather than just `<thing>`? That seems to be all it would do?

Comment: @cfr sorry, mail where? :D the command is a remnant of something I was testing but if the OP wants a replica of the above picture, it's going to become more useful.  :)

Comment: @Alenanno The edited question includes an attempt to ping you, but I don't think you can do that in questions, so I thought you might want to be pinged. Apologies if not.

Comment: @cfr Ah! No, thank you! :D That was kind of you. Thanks for the ping, you're right, pings in questions do not work at all, so your ping was certainly useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Mellon For small remarks or requests on a particular answer or a comment, please use the comments instead of editing the main question.  Perhaps have a read of [this introduction to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) too :) .  Also, if you want to accept an answer, you can [use the tick mark below the question's vote marks](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852).  This gives the person (and you!) some reputation and is [part of how the site identifies good questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Mellon, did you accidentally create another login instead of logging in with your usual account? I will ask for a merge of your two accounts, so you get back to one, but you should be able to accept if you manage to login from your first account. :) You will also be able to comment on your own question.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `rotate=\angle-90` to your node printed by the foreach.

**Edit:** Since you don't want the image in the OP, here's your fixed version. Note that you can draw the colored arcs without "cutting" with a white circle in the middle. I have fixed that. I think the descriptions are as you would want them (German characters should be fixed). If you don't want them colored, remove the line `\color{\farbe}` from the code.

**Edit 2:** See below for a different version.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri, intersections, decorations.text}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{chemfig,xstring}

\tikzset{
    point/.style={minimum size=#1},
    point/.default=0pt,
    bent text/.style={postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                text along path,
                reverse path=true,
                text align/align=center,
                text={| \Large\bfseries\color{\farbe}|#1}
            }
        }
    }
}


\def\colorlist{{"green!60", "orange!60", "red!60", "yellow!60", "blue!60"}}

\begin{document}
\setatomsep{2.5em}
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}\tiny
 \foreach \anfang/\ende/\descr [count=\ix starting from 0] in {%
    25/100/{klein polar (hydrophil)},
    104/170/{groß, polar (hydrophil)},
    174/254/{mittiere Polarität},
    258/314/{groß unpolar},
    318/381/{klein, unpolar}}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\farbe{\colorlist[\ix]}
    \fill[\farbe] (\anfang:6cm) -- (\anfang:12cm) arc (\anfang:\ende:12cm) -- (\ende:6cm) arc (\ende:\anfang:6cm);
    \path[bent text={\descr}] (\anfang:5cm) arc (\anfang:\ende:5cm);
}
% mit count=\i werden die Kreise nummeriert
% der zugehörige Winkel wird mit evaluate aus dieser Nummer berechnet
% insgesamt werden (bis zu) 20 Kreise auf 360 Grad gleichmäßig verteilt
\foreach [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \angle using int((\i-1)*360/20), evaluate=\i as \midangle using int((\i-1.5)*360/20), remember=\midangle as \lastmid (initially -27)] \text in {%
 1,2,3,4,
  \schemestart \chemnameinit{}\chemname{\chemfig{C(=[3]O)(-[1]OH)(-[6]CH_2(-[6]CH(-[5]NH_2)(-[7]C(=[6]O)(-[1]OH))))}}{Asparaginsäure\\Asp\\D} \schemestop,
  \schemestart \chemnameinit{} \chemname{\chemfig{CH(-[3]NH_2)(-[1]C(=[2]OH)(-[7]OH))(-[6]CH_2(-[6]C(=[5]O)(-[7]NH_2)))}}{Asparagin\\Asn\\N}\schemestop
  ,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20% Beschriftung der Kreise
}{

\node[point=2.2em, rotate=\angle-90] (node\i) at (\angle:9) {\text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Matching the OP

Here's another version to fit the one in your image.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri, intersections, decorations.text}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{chemfig,xstring}

\definecolor{xlime}{RGB}{228,246,13}
\definecolor{xpink}{RGB}{245,109,175}
\definecolor{xorange}{RGB}{232,117,53}
\definecolor{xgreen}{RGB}{151,184,43}
\definecolor{xblue}{RGB}{144,181,236}

\tikzset{
    point/.style={minimum size=#1},
    point/.default=0pt,
    bent text/.style={postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                text along path,
                reverse path=true,
                text align/align=center,
                text={| \Large\bfseries\color{\farbe}|#1}
            }
        }
    }
}

\newcommand\aminoacids[4][black]{
    \node[point=2.2em, minimum width=5cm,rotate=\angle-90, inner sep=2mm] (node#2) at (#3) {#4};
    \path[green, name path=around] (node#2.north west) -- (node#2.north east) -- (node#2.south east) -- (node#2.south west) -- cycle;
    \path[name path={tris#2}] (\midangle:12cm) -- (0,0) -- (\lastmid:12cm) -- cycle;
    \path[name intersections={of={tris#2} and around, name=i, total=\t}];
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \filldraw[draw=black, fill=#1] (i-1) -- (i-2) -- (i-4) -- (i-3) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
}

\def\colorlist{{"xgreen", "xorange", "xpink", "xlime", "xblue"}}

\begin{document}
\setatomsep{2.5em}
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}\tiny
 \foreach \anfang/\ende/\descr [count=\ix starting from 0] in {%
    25/100/{klein polar (hydrophil)},
    104/170/{groß, polar (hydrophil)},
    174/254/{mittiere Polarität},
    258/314/{groß unpolar},
    318/381/{klein, unpolar}}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\farbe{\colorlist[\ix]}
    \path[bent text={\descr}] (\anfang:5cm) arc (\anfang:\ende:5cm);
}

\foreach [count=\i, 
    evaluate=\i as \angle using int((\i-1)*360/20), 
    evaluate=\i as \midangle using int((\i-1.5)*360/20), 
    evaluate=\midangle as \lastmid using int((\i-.5)*360/20)
    ] 
    \text/\colr in {%
        1/0,2/0,3/0,4/0,
        \schemestart \chemnameinit{}\chemname{\chemfig{C(=[3]O)(-[1]OH)(-[6]CH_2(-[6]CH(-[5]NH_2)(-[7]C(=[6]O)(-[1] OH))))}}{Asparaginsäure\\Asp\\D} \schemestop/0,
        \schemestart \chemnameinit{} \chemname{\chemfig{CH(-[3]NH_2)(-[1]C(=[2]OH)(-[7]OH))(-[6]CH_2(-[6]C(=[5]O)(-[7]  NH_2)))}}{Asparagin\\Asn\\N}\schemestop/0
        ,7/1,8/1,9/1,10/2,11/2,12/2,13/3,14/3,15/3,16/3,17/4,18/4,19/4,20/4% Beschriftung der Kreise
}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\farbe{\colorlist[\colr]}
    \aminoacids[\farbe]{\i}{\angle:9}{\text}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```